# what is the problem of the following code?

Tags: c++, overloading

I overload the operator (), as following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {

    public:
    Test() {};
    void operator () (Test);

};

void Test::operator () (Test test) {
    cout << "yes";
}

int main() {
    Test test;
    (test);
}
```

when I run it, the "yes" does not show up?
any problem with the code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With that signature for `operator()` you would need to call it with something like:

```
test(test);
```

or possibly

```
test(Test());
```

`(test)` is just an expression which has type `Test` that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 6):

It should be something like

```
test( test );
```

so that `operator()` is invoked. When you just put braces around a variable name that doesn't trigger `operator()` - both braces must follow the variable name.

Comment: void operator () (Test); the parameter is ()(Test), so should not we pass it as (test)?

Comment: `Test::operator()` takes a `Test` parameter by value as well.

Comment: In fact it should be something like: `test( test );` (call member function `operator()` on `test`, passing (another) `test` as argument.

Answer (score 0):

`Run it like test()`. It's a function operator overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `test();` not `(test)`. That is after you change the signature to remove the unused argument ... change to  `void operator () ();`

Have a look at wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object